# Is there a word or adjective to describe an unnecessary correction?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

When in casual conversation, being full accurate or detailed on what you mean isn't always necessary. For example, if I were to tell someone I want to buy a certain "waterproof" speaker and they correct me by saying it is water resistant, although it wasn't necessary. In the context of that conversation, they understand what I mean and it isn't needed to make clarification.

Comment: Maybe the other person was being _pedantic._

Comment: six of one, half a dozen of the other, comes to mind.